# How do I check for extra inputs in scanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using `scanf()` to take in a value for x and I want to check if anything other than a single integer is entered; if it is, I want to retake the input.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int x;
    char c;

    int input = scanf("%i%c", &x, &c);

    while (input != 2 || c != '\n')
    {
        input = scanf("%i%c", &x, &c);
    }

    printf("x = %i\n", x);
}
```

At the moment, when I enter 2 integers separated by a space, e.g `23 43`, the program prints out 43, instead of asking for the input again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `strtol()` that checks if all characters in a string have been converted to the number. Read the string using `fgets` or any other line reader and extract the number from it:

```
char buffer[4096];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
char *endptr;
long result = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 10);
if(*endptr != '\0') { /* There is more input! */ }
```

As a bonus, you can read non-decimal numbers and also check if the entered number is within the acceptable range.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without having a long int?

Comment: You cast the result to `int` if you want: `int result = (int)strtol...`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with other way because int only allow single number example:1000 you can do like:1000 2000 but theres another way you can ask the user the count of numbers he going to type then make a loop for scanf for the count of numbers then you can do whatever you want here an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int loopTime = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int result = 0;

    printf("Enter the count of number you need to enter: ");//the number of times scanf going to loop
    scanf("%d", &loopTime);

    printf("Now enter the numbers you going to store but after every number you need to press enter\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < loopTime; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        result += temp;
    }

    printf("The Result is: %i", result);
    return 0;
}
```